# End of file using ByteBuffer and FileChannel

Tags: java, bytebuffer, filechannel

I write a small code, say

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
int w= fc.read(buffer);
System.out.println(w);
w= fc.read(buffer);
System.out.println(w);
w= fc.read(buffer);
System.out.println(w);
```

say the file contains 10 bytes, the result appeared on the screen is 10, 0, 0, but no -1 appers as the end of the file, why?

Answer (score 2):

If the `int` returned by the `read()` method is -1 you have reached the end of the file.

**EDIT** Re your edit, the value returned by the `read()` method is a *count.*

The first time, you read 10 bytes, and the buffer's capacity was 10 bytes, so you (a) printed `10` and (b) filled the buffer.

All the other times, the buffer was already full, because you didn't `clear()` it, so nothing was read and zero was returned, so you printed zero.

If you call `buffer.clear()` after the first `read()`, the next `read()` will return -1.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't need to be more specific when every `read()` method in the JDK does the same thing.

Comment: I have make my questions more specific

Comment: @Sotirios As every `read()` method in the JDK returns -1 at end of stream I consider your suggestion to be a complete waste of time, and indeed counterproductive. There's a reason they all behave they same way. It's called 'design'. You only have to learn it once. Not once per `FileChannel` and again per `FileReader,` which incidentally wasn't mentioned in the question, and again per `SocketChannel,` `BufferedReader,` `PushbackInputStream,` etc. etc. etc. Frankly your suggestion is ridiculous.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Alternatively you could just have assumed that I was answering the question in the context of `FileChannel,` which *was* mentioned in the question, which only has three `read()` methods, all three of which behave as described.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm baffled by the thought process that asks me 'which read() method is that?' because it wants me to say 'it applies to every read method in the JDK'. Try making yourself clear, or should I say 'explicit', next time.

Comment: Yes, I misspelt your name. I think you should delete some of this nonsense, given that you eventually accepted 'Every read() method in the JDK'. I still don't understand why I had to explain it several times first.

Answer (score 1):

If the int returned by reader is -1 then you have reached to end of file.

for example:-

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("yourfilename");

int data = reader.read();

if(data != -1){
 // your code
}
```

Comment: You should give your example with `FileChannel`.

Comment: @user3495562 Se the edit.. May that helps. But I think you should give your code first so that we can see what you are doing.